# Array returns NaN

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-animate

I have a array that contains multiple counters and it's accessed via a string that i `counters[div_block_id+'counter']` and at first I assign a value of zero to each counter but once the div is clicked the counter returns not a number.
Initialization of array and its content.

```
var counters = new Array();
// Searches for every div that have an id attribute
$('div').each(function () {
    if (!this.id) {} else {
        var id = this.id + '_counter';
        counters.push(id); //add id to counters array 
        counters[id] = 0; //initialize as 0 the counter of corresponding id 
        console.log(counters); //Logs the array
    }
});
```

You can see a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2wqKt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing JavaScript arrays and objects. Arrays are based on numerical indices only. For example, when the first time your function runs, you'll array will look as

```
counters.push(id); // your array will be counters[0] = id;
counters[id] = 0; // nothing will happen because it's an invalid index
```

You need to use an object to store keys and values. For example

```
var counters = {}; // short code for object
// Searches for every div that have an id attribute
$('div').each(function () {
    if (!this.id) {} else {
        var id = this.id + '_counter';
        counters[id] = 0; //initialize as 0 the counter of corresponding id 
        console.log(counters[id]); //Logs the array
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's still returning NaN, but I really appreatiate the time you took to explain this, very helpful

Comment: It shouldn't unless there is something else in your code causing the error. You can check this example http://jsfiddle.net/gJAL3/

Comment: Oh, at first it's ok but when the onclick happens then it returns NaN check the js fiddle in the question, thank you!

Comment: In line 184 (javascript), you are calling expand with a div id horizontal_bar but you don't have a div with that id in your HTML.

Comment: Well thank you very much for your time and help! It workedbut not as supposed to,but its my code there's something wrong but the suggestion you made corrected the NaN part. Again THANK YOU SO MUCH!